# How to add AAD Group as SharePoint Online visitors

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am able to add O365 group as the SharePoint site visitor with this command

```
Add-SPOUser -Site 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite01 -LoginName testgroup01@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -Group 'testsite01 Visitors'
```

I am going to add AAD group as the SharePoint site visitor , i have found the AAD Group GUID by this command:

```
Get-AzureADGroup  -SearchString testgroup01 | Select DisplayName, ObjectID
```

Then i add the AAD Group with this command (I have confirmed the GUID is valid)

```
Add-SPOUser -Site 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite01 -LoginName 'c:0t.c|tenant|af143a4a-f7f0-430c-b83b-c9b5dxxx2ef' -Group 'testsite01 Visitors'
```

The error message:

```
Add-SPOUser : Group cannot be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-SPOUser -Site 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite01
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-SPOUser], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AddSPOUser
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong ? thx !!

Answer (score 0):

You may try PnP PowerShell to add an office 365 group to a SharePoint group.

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "password" 
$siteURL = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/modernteam" 
#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials   
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName GroupLee@xxx.onmicrosoft.com -Identity 'modernteam Visitors'
Write-Host "---"
```

Comment: I need AAD Group (Sync from AD)